# How to prevent the user from interrupting window.scrollTo()?

Tags: javascript, scroll

I have a piece of code which uses `window.scrollTo()`, and I want to stop the user from interrupting the scrolling until it is finished.

```
let isMoving = false;

const scroll_keys = { 37: 1, 38: 1, 39: 1, 40: 1 };

preventDefault = e => {
  console.log(isMoving);
  if (!isMoving) return;
  e = e || window.event;
  if (e.preventDefault) e.preventDefault();
  e.returnValue = false;
};

preventDefaultForScrollKeys = e => {
  if (!isMoving) return;
  if (keys[e.keyCode]) {
    preventDefault(e);
    return false;
  }
};

document.addEventListener('wheel', preventDefault, { passive: false });
document.addEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', preventDefault, { passive: false });
document.addEventListener('scroll', preventDefault, { passive: false });
window.ontouchmove = preventDefault;
document.onkeydown = preventDefaultForScrollKeys;

function scrollTo(offset, callback) {
  const onScroll = () => {
    const scrollTop = window.scrollTop || window.pageYOffset;

    if (scrollTop === offset) {
      window.removeEventListener('scroll', onScroll);
      callback();
    }
  };
  window.addEventListener('scroll', onScroll);

  onScroll();
  window.scrollTo({
    top: offset,
    behavior: 'smooth',
  });
}
```

I set `isMoving = true` before the call to `window.scrollTo`, and set it back to false in the callback, like this:

```
isMoving = true; scrollTo(0, () => { isMoving = false; });
```

I expect this to completely prevent the user from interrupting the scrolling but it doesn't work properly. It seems to work, but not every time, and it seems quite buggy.

Comment: i think it should be `if (isMoving) return;` without the negation. Where are you changing `isMoving = true`?

Comment: I set it right before I call window.scrollTo and I'm pretty sure it needs the negation. But thank you so far. :)

Comment: The question is not very clear to me as it doesn't detail exactly how things are not working. Having said that, note that `scroll` events are _not_ cancellable. You are right to use `preventDefault` on the `wheel` event, as well as `touchmove`. There's also `touchstart`, `touchend` and `keypress`, which might be of interest.